# How to maintain alignment and spacing in Viewbox

Tags: xaml, spacing, viewbox

I have a list of labels and values. For instance (this sample is for illustrative purposes):

```
Tim        0.333
Fred       0.357
Fernando   0.300
```

I would like to be able to add to this list and have the text shrink so the list will fill the available space but not exceed it. I would also like to be able to resize the window and have the list fill the available space. I tried using a Viewbox to accomplish this and failed in two different ways:

1) I tried using a grid and surrounding each label and value with a Viewbox. This maintained my spacing between the label and value, but the labels and values were different sizes. Here is the code for the user control that displays the player information:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Viewbox.Player"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Average, StringFormat={}{0:0.000}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

2) I tried surrounding the grid with the Viewbox. This sized the text as I wanted, but now my spacing was gone and each line was centered.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Viewbox.Player"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Average, StringFormat={}{0:0.000}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

I have been dancing around this issue for a while now. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: And using margin does not help ? Please post your xaml as well.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. A list with a variable number of items should be top-aligned. If the items exceed the available space, they should be scrollable. You should use an ordinary ItemsControl or ListBox for your display. Varying font sizes is just ugly.

Comment: @Clemens - As I said, my sample was for illustrative purposes. I was trying to boil down a simple case that would represent what I am trying to do. In my situation, I definitely do not want a top-aligned list with empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by inserting a blank column. This preserves the alignment and font sizes (up to a point):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Viewbox.Player"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Average, StringFormat={}{0:0.000}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

Unfortunately, it breaks down a bit when the window is sized very tall:

[image]

However, for my purposes, I am able to limit the total height, so this is not a problem.